# Keep inline products isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I keep this inline? Even vertical-align: top; is not working. As you can see on the image of the product is not perfectly align or not inline. I think the problem is the product name. The product name should be inline. Btw I'm using an isotope jquery, if I remove the script of isotope, the products are inline. What should I do?

**CSS:**

```
//Container of each products
.product-feature {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Vitesse-Bold';
    vertical-align: top;
}

//Product-Item-Details and Product name(Font Size)
.product-item-details .product-item-name {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: -4px !important;
}

//Class of product name
.product-item-name {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 5px 0;
    webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}

//Product Item name font style, colors, text-transform
//and etc.
.product-item-details .product-item-name a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Vitesse-Bold;
    color: #333;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    display: inline-block;
    word-break: break-word;
}

//Hover item name
.product-item-details .product-item-name a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}

//Container of each product image
.product-image-container {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

//Wrapper of Image
.product-image-wrapper {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

//Product-image Photo
.product-image-photo {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

//styles of brands
.product-item-brand {
    font-family: Vitesse-Light;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    margin: 0 0px 0px;
}

//min-height of product-brand
.product-item-details .product-item-brand {
    min-height: 20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<?php include('admin/admin_server.php');?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Shop | Sneakix</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/font-awesome.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="../assets/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="../assets/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/animate.css" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Amaran Notification  -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/amaran.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/animate.min.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include('header.php');?>
        <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
            <div id="form-shop">
                <div class="product-shop-container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="widget widget-filter-links clearfix">
                                <h3 class="text-block">BRANDS</h3>
                                <ul class="custom-filter nobottommargin" data-container="#products" data-active-class="active-filter">
                                    <li class="widget-filter-reset active-filter"><a href="#" data-filter="*">Clear</a></li>
                                    <?php foreach(get_brand_by_gender() as $cat_row): ?>
                                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".<?=$cat_row['brand_id']?>"><?=$cat_row['brand_name']?></a></li>
                                    <?php endforeach;?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <h3 class="text-block">FILTER BY</h3>
                            <ul id="category-tabs">
                                <li><a href="javascript:void" class="filter-title"><i class="fa fa-plus dim"></i>Category</a>
                                    <ul class="brands-filter">
                                        <?=get_shop_category()?>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul id="category-tabs">
                                <li><a href="javascript:void" class="filter-title"><i class="fa fa-plus dim"></i>Price</a>
                                    <ul class="shop-sorting">
                                        <li class="widget-filter-reset active-filter"><a href="#" data-sort-by="original-order">Clear</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" data-sort-by="price_lh">Price: Low to High</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" data-sort-by="price_hl">Price: High to Low</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul id="category-tabs">
                                <li><a href="javascript:void" class="filter-title"><i class="fa fa-plus dim"></i>Size</a>
                                    <ul class="brands-filter">
                                        <li>Radio Button Size</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div id="products" data-layout="fitRows">
                                <?=get_products_by_segment()?>
                            </div>
                            <hr class="transparent">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php include('footer.php');?>
        <!--External JavaScripts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
        <!--Bootstrap Scripts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!--Functions JavaScript-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/ajaxFunctions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/functions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/customize.js"></script>
        <!---Amaran Notification  -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/jquery.amaran.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            show_cart_contents();
            show_cart_count();
            show_account_contents();
            show_search_contents();
            get_products_brand();
        </script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('#products').isotope({
                    transitionDuration: '0.65s',
                    getSortData: {
                        name: '.product-item-name',
                        price_lh: function( itemElem ) {
                            if( $(itemElem).find('.price').length > 0 ) {
                                var price = $(itemElem).find('.price').text();
                            } else {
                                var price = $(itemElem).find('.price').text();
                            }

                            priceNum = price.split("₱");
                            return parseFloat( priceNum[1] );
                        },
                        price_hl: function( itemElem ) {
                            if( $(itemElem).find('.price').length > 0 ) {
                                var price = $(itemElem).find('.price').text();
                            } else {
                                var price = $(itemElem).find('.price').text();
                            }

                            priceNum = price.split("₱");

                            return parseFloat( priceNum[1] );
                        }
                    },
                    sortAscending: {
                        name: true,
                        price_lh: true,
                        price_hl: false
                    }
                });
                $('.custom-filter:not(.no-count)').children('li:not(.widget-filter-reset)').each( function(){
                    var element = $(this),
                    elementFilter = element.children('a').attr('data-filter'),
                    elementFilterContainer = element.parents('.custom-filter').attr('data-container');

                    elementFilterCount = Number( jQuery(elementFilterContainer).find( elementFilter ).length );
                    element.append('<span>'+ elementFilterCount +'</span>');
                });

                $('.shop-sorting li').click( function() {
                    $('.shop-sorting').find('li').removeClass( 'active-filter' );
                    $(this).addClass( 'active-filter' );
                    var sortByValue = $(this).find('a').attr('data-sort-by');
                    $('#products').isotope({sortBy: sortByValue});
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Function to display products

```
//Get Products by Brand
    function get_products_by_segment() {
        GLOBAL $db_conn;
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $search_query= "SELECT p.*, pe.*, pbt.* FROM tblproduct p JOIN (SELECT p.product_id, MIN(pe.product_extension_id) AS product_extension_id FROM tblproduct p LEFT JOIN tblproduct_extension pe ON pe.product_id = p.product_id WHERE p.segment_id='$id' GROUP BY product_id) product_unique LEFT JOIN tblproduct_extension pe ON pe.product_extension_id = product_unique.product_extension_id LEFT JOIN tblbrand pbt ON pbt.brand_name = p.product_brand WHERE p.product_id = product_unique.product_id";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $search_query);

        function get_image_by_id($product_id) {
            GLOBAL $db_conn;
               $search_query = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct_carousel WHERE product_id = $product_id LIMIT 1";
               $image_query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $search_query);
               return $image_query;
        }

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            ?>
                <div class="product-feature <?=$row['brand_id']?> clearfix" >
                    <a href="details.php?view_product=<?=$row['product_id']?>&id=<?=$row['segment_id']?>" class="product-item-photo" tabindex="-1" draggable="false" title="<?=$row['product_name']?>">
                        <span class="product-image-container" style="width: 307px;">
                            <span class="product-image-wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 100%;">
                                <?php foreach (get_image_by_id($row['product_id']) as $row_slides):?>
                                                    <img class="product-image-photo" src="../assets/uploads/<?=$row['product_brand']?>/<?=$row_slides['product_images']?>" alt="<?=$row['product_name']?>" style="width=307px; height=307px;" draggable="false">
                                                <?php endforeach;?>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <?php if($row['product_stocks'] == 0) {?>
                        <span class="outofstock-label">SOLD OUT</span>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="product-item-details">
                        <strong class="product-item-name">
                            <a href="details.php?view_product=<?=$row['product_id']?>&id=<?=$row['segment_id']?>"><?=$row['product_name']?></a>
                        </strong>
                        <p class="product-item-brand"><?=$row['product_brand']?></p>
                        <div class="product-price-details">
                            <span class="price">&#8369;<?=number_format($row['product_price'], 2)?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
        }
        return $row;
    }
```

[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coC01.png)

Comment: You should post yor entire code, not only the css

Comment: I posted the entire code brother. I'm sorry.

Comment: Help me guys...